# send/receive Datastream througth USB-port in java

Tags: java, usb, jusb

before I begin with working with java an jUSB library I would like to know if is it useful for me.
I am using Windows 7 and I wold like to receive and to send stream data throw USB.
Should I use jUSB?
Is it possible with java?.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at [JSR-80](http://today.java.net/article/2006/07/05/java-and-usb).. it seems like [jUSB](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-usb.html) will do the trick